# Cordova Hybrid app using Salesforce mobile SDK with Community and custom VF login page - Issue with login from mobile app

Tags: visualforce, mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, hybrid, salesforce-sdk-hybrid

I am trying to add a custom Visualforce login page to my hybrid app, which is connected to a SF community. What I have done is, created a Visualforce page, which collects the User's username and password and override this VF page in community login page settings.

When I try to login through a web browser into the community, it works well and redirected to the web landing page. But, when I try to do it through the mobile app (created with SF Mobile SDK, i.e. forceios CLI), it is also redirecting to the web landing page instead of mobile app.

Can some one please guide me how we can redirect the user to the mobile app after successful login if the request is coming from app.
Appreciate your immediate assistance

Comment: Experts , Any update here ?

Answer (score 0):

One of our user guides shows some steps which may be helpful. Although there is mention of testing with our pre-built container app 'BizCaddy' I think the setup of the community will be very similar.

http://mobilecaddy.net/userguide/CustomCommunityLogin_V.2.pdf

Hope this helps!

Justin